# How to Get value from toggle button in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to get value from toggle button.so please help me to solve this problem.and give code with discription...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez" / "do my work for me"

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options,

1. Set a listener for check change

   ```
   ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
   toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   String.valueOf(buttonView.isChecked()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
   ```

Or

2. Check directly with [isChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29)